# How can I index properties in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

How can I index properties in the Node and Relationship classes I created in Memgraph with GQLAlchemy? Is it possible to create only a Label index?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Memgraph's documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/gqlalchemy/how-to-guides/ogm/index-labels-and-properties). There are some great and simple examples that explain the process. For example,

```
from gqlalchemy import Memgraph, Node, Field
db = Memgraph()

class Animal(Node, index=True, db=db):
    name: str

class Human(Node):
    id: str = Field(index=True, db=db)
```

In the first class, `Animal`, the class argument `index` is set to `True`. That means that Memgraph will create a label `index` on the label `Animal`.

The other class, `Human`, has a `Field()` `index` argument set to `True`. Hence, Memgraph will create a label-property `index` on the property `id` of every node labeled `Human`.